# Using xml for a configuration file

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to figure out how to use `XmlTextReader` and `XmlTextWriter` for the configuration file of my program(s).

The xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Base>
    <Global>
        <some_config_value>86400</some_config_value>
        <test1>t_1</test1>
        <test2>t_2</test2>
        <test3>t_3</test3>
        <test4>t_4</test4>
    </Global>
    <test_head>
        <test5>t_5</test5>
        <test6>t_6</test6>
    </test_head>
</Base>
```

And here is the class I have so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

namespace my_program.Global
{
    class CXMLConfig
    {
        private string path;

        public CXMLConfig(string filepath)
        {
            path = filepath;
        }

        public string XmlReadValue(string Section, string Key)
        {
            XmlTextReader textReader = new XmlTextReader(path);
            ReadElements readEl = new ReadElements(textReader, Section, Key);
            textReader.Close();
            return readEl.Value;
        }

        private class ReadElements
        {
            XmlTextReader textReader;
            string Section;
            string Key;

            private bool inBase = false;
            private bool inSection = false;
            private bool inKey = false;

            public string Value { get; private set; }

            public ReadElements(XmlTextReader textReader_set, string Section_set, string Key_set)
            {
                Value = "";

                this.textReader = textReader_set;
                this.Section = Section_set;
                this.Key = Key_set;

                textReader.Read();
                while (textReader.Read())
                {
                    // Move to fist element
                    textReader.MoveToElement();

                    string nodetype = textReader.NodeType.ToString();

                    if (textReader.LocalName == "Base")
                    {
                        if (nodetype == "Element")
                        {
                            if (!inBase)
                                inBase = true;
                        }
                        else if (nodetype == "EndElement")
                        {
                            if (inBase)
                                inBase = false;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (inBase && textReader.LocalName == Section)
                    {
                        if (nodetype == "Element")
                        {
                            if (!inSection)
                                inSection = true;
                        }
                        else if (nodetype == "EndElement")
                        {
                            if (inSection)
                                inSection = false;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (inBase && inSection && textReader.LocalName == Key)
                    {
                        if (inSection)
                        {
                            if (nodetype == "Element")
                            { 
                                if (!inKey)
                                    inKey = true;
                            }
                            else if (nodetype == "EndElement")
                            {
                                if (inKey)
                                    inKey = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (inBase && inSection && inKey)
                    {
                        if (nodetype == "Text")
                        {
                            Value = textReader.Value.ToString();
                            //Console.WriteLine(Value);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

So first of all, this is probably bad XML.. I have never used it before and it does look a little.. odd. And then there is the fact that I wrote this whole `ReadElements` class to read a value out of the config file, but I imagined there would be a much simpler way to do this with `XmlTextReader` (but I couldn't find it). And then lastly, I have yet to figure out how to update a value in the xml file using `XmlTextWriter` without re-writing the whole xml file from top to bottom.

Comment: Do you have to use XmlTextReader? You might find XmlDocument or XDocument to be much easier to use here.

Comment: Use XDocument and built in web/app.config it's much more easy and proped

Comment: I'll check it out, hope it does the trick ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `XmlSerializer` to serialize and deserialize an arbitrary configuration class. Here is a sample implementation:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    ValueA,
    ValueB
}

[Serializable]
public class Configuration : PersistableObject
{
    public double A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public MyEnum C { get; set; }
}

public class PersistableObject
{
    public static T Load<T>(string fileName) where T : PersistableObject, new()
    {
        T result = default(T);

        using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(fileName))
        {
            result = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).Deserialize(stream) as T;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public void Save<T>(string fileName) where T : PersistableObject
    {
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.CreateNew))
        {
            new XmlSerializer(typeof(T)).Serialize(stream, this);
        }
    }
}
```

For more information on how to configure XmlSerializer, have a look at the MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx

Comment: Can't for the life of me figure out what to do with "EnumMember". I get the error `The type or namespace name 'EnumMember' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`. I have been googeling but couldn't find the answer.. could you elaborate a little?

Comment: I confused XmlSerializer with DataContractSerializer here. You can just omit the `EnumMember` attribute, it's not required.

Comment: Ah I see.. that did it ;) I still have no idea how to actually use this though. I have never used `enum` before.. can't figure out what to do. I did already fix my problem using `XDocument` but I'd like to find out how you intended this to work, I'd like to learn. Could you maybe provide a quick usage-example?

Comment: The `enum` was just an example of the different types of data you may want to serialize. The idea here is that you have a configuration class that holds all your configuration data in the form of public properties. Somewhere in your program, you call PersistableObject.Load<Configuration>(...) to load a XML configuration file. This returns an instance of your configuration class, which you can use in your program. After having made changes to the configuration instance, you can write these changes back to disk by calling the Save(...) method on the instance.